# Tap into webpack resolve/loader to add fallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react app (student-portal).

My folder structure is as follows:

```
\- build
  - webpack.config.js
\- src
  - App.js
  - components\
    - Login\
      - Login.scss
      - Login.js
    - Dashboard\
    - Register\
  - redux\
  - helpers\
```

My webpack is pretty standard.

```
 var path = require('path');
 var webpack = require('webpack');
 module.exports = {
     entry: './src/app.js',
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
         filename: 'app.bundle.js'
     },
     module: {
         loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 loader: 'babel-loader',
                 query: {
                     presets: ['es2015']
                 }
             }
         ]
     },
     stats: {
         colors: true
     },
     devtool: 'source-map'
 };
```

I want to build on top of this app. So I published this app to npm (local). My folder structure is now:

```
\- node_modules
  - student-portal\
\ - src\
\ - build\
```

What I would like is an ability to replace/extend existing components and not have to copy the existing files.

So, if I create a new file, I want webpack to use it. If this file doesn't exist, it should look into `node_modules/student-portal\src`.

So webpack should look into `src` file first and then into `node_modules\student-portal\src`.

I tried creating a resolver function:

```
var MyResolver = {
  apply: function(resolver) {
    resolver.plugin('module', function(request, callback) {
      console.log(request.request); // this only consoles node_modules not .js files
    });
  }
};
```

But this doesn't console .js files. I also played around with number of other plugins like NormalModuleReplacementPlugin, ResolverPlugin etc with no success.

Any pointer on how I can tap into webpack resolve and replace path if file doesn't exist would be very much appreciated. Ideally I would like to extend existing components and have webpack replace path to old component with path to new component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use the [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) options, since it does what you describe. However, since the question is about resolve plugin, I'll try to write one as well.

### Resolve.modules

Here's an example with `lodash` as the target module. We can set up a structure like this:

```
node_modules
  `--lodash
src
  |--lodash
  |    `-- zip.js
  `-index.js
```

`zip.js` can just be something like `export default () => 'local zip'`

In our `webpack.config.js`, do

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },
  ...
}
```

In our index.js, let's import `zip` and `isObject`.

```
// src/index.js
import zip from 'lodash/zip';
import isObject from 'lodash/isObject';

console.log(zip()); // 'local zip'
console.log(isObject({ a: 100 }));  // 'true'
```

This is essentially what you want, but instead of writing relative path to your custom components, you write module path instead.

### Resolve Plugin

But since the question asks about plugin, let's give it a try! I commented on your q's earlier, but then found out the plugin system has changed in webpack 4. I'm on node v10 so some of the syntaxes might not work in older versions.

The directory structure:

```
node_modules
  `--lodash
src
  |--components
  |    `-- zip.js
  `-index.js
```

First, a quick overview of a resolve plugin. Webpack allows us to tap into multiple hooks in the resolve pipeline ([you can see the full list here](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/95e27d33d052fe955d297c6165111cfd0cc03240/lib/ResolverFactory.js#L164)). We're particularly interested in `resolve`, `parsedResolve` and `module`. Our plan is:

```
1. Tap into the `resolve` hook  
2. Is the resolve request points to our 'components' folder?  
   - If not, go to **step 3**.  
   - If yes, is there something there it can use?  
       - If not, point it to `lodash` module instead.  
       - If yes, go to **step 3**.  
3. Continue to the next hook in the pipeline (`parsedResolve`).
```

When we tap into a hook, we'll get a very useful `request` object with these props:

- `context`: contain the issuer (absolute path to `index.js`)
- `path`: the directory of the issuer (absolute path to `src`)
- `request`: the request string ('./components/zip')

With that, we can write our plugin:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

class CustomResolverPlugin {
  constructor ({ dir, moduleName }) {
    this.dir = dir;  // absolute path to our 'components' folder
    this.moduleName = moduleName; // name of the module, 'lodash' in this case
  }
  apply(resolver) {
    resolver.getHook('resolve').tapAsync('CustomResolverPlugin', (request, resolveContext, callback) => {

      // 1. check if the request is point to our component folder
      // resolver.join is same as path.join, but memoized
      const { dir } = path.parse(resolver.join(request.path, request.request));
      const match = dir === this.dir;

      if (match) {

        // 2. get the name of the file being requested & check if it exists.
        // in import zip from `./src/components/zip`, 'zip' is the name.
        const { name } = path.parse(request.request);
        const pathExist = fs.existsSync(path.join(this.dir, `${name}`));
        if (!pathExist) {

          // create a new request object.
          // we'll swap the request to something like 'lodash/zip'
          const _request = {
            ...request,
            request: `${this.moduleName}/${name}`
          }
          // swap the target hook to 'module' to resolve it as a module.
          const _target = resolver.ensureHook('module');
          return resolver.doResolve(_target, _request, null, resolveContext, callback);
        }
      }

      // 3. otherwise continue to the next hook
      const target = resolver.ensureHook('parsedResolve');
      return resolver.doResolve(target, request, null, resolveContext, callback);
    });
  }
}
```

Usage in `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    plugins: [
      new CustomResolverPlugin({
        dir: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
        moduleName: 'lodash',
      }),
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

In your index.js:

```
import zip from './components/zip';
import isObject from './components/isObject';

console.log(zip(['a', 'b'], [1, 2])); // 'local zip'
console.log(isObject({ a: 100 }));    // true
```

Hope it helps!